# BLAS/LAPACK routine for doing Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, blas

I'm a new user of BLAS/Lapack, and I'm just wondering is there a routine which does Gaussian elimination or even Gaussian-Jordan elimination? I googled and looked at their documentations, but still couldn't find them.

Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Comment: Does it have to be Gaussian/Gauss-Jordan or can it be any algorithm which finds exact solutions to linear equations?

Comment: @Matt Ball I think I may prefer Gaussian/Gauss-Jordan because the resulting matrix will be put in the echelon form. Will other algorithms also produce row echelon form?

Comment: @KelvinLee Just curious, what are some other operations that row-echelon form would be helpful for? (I am just wanting to learn more, not suggesting this isn't a valid use case.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gaussian elimination is basically the same as LU factorization. The routine xGETRF computes the LU factorization (e.g., [DGETRF](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgetrf.f) for real double precision matrices). The U factor corresponds to the matrix after Gaussian elimination. The U factor is stored in the upper triangular part (including the diagonal) of the matrix A on exit.

LU factorization / Gaussian elimination is commonly used to solve linear systems of equations. You can use the xGETRS routine to solve a linear system once you have computed the LU factorization.